# Zoom not detecting camera and microphone on MBP 2015 - exclamation point in triangle

Tags: zoom

I've an issue with the camera and microphone I need to use Zoom for my class but after opening Zoom, it asks for permission, no one has permission left.

[image: zoom photo]

Comment: Which versions of macOS and Zoom are you running?

Comment: macOS Monterey, and latest version zoom